# Read range of files in pySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I need to read contiguous files in pySpark.  The following works for me.

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext    
file = "events.parquet/exportDay=2015090[1-7]"
df = sqlContext.read.load(file)
```

How do I read files 8-14?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use curly braces.

```py
file = "events.parquet/exportDay=201509{08,09,10,11,12,13,14}"
```

Here's a similar question on stack overflow: [Pyspark select subset of files using regex glob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31543766/pyspark-select-subset-of-files-using-regex-glob-from-s3). They suggest either using curly braces, OR performing multiple reads and then unioning the objects (whether they are RDDs or data frames or whatever, there should be some way).

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 2):

It uses shell globbing, I believe.

The post: [How to read multiple text files into a single RDD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24029873/how-to-read-multiple-text-files-into-a-single-rdd)

Seems to suggest the below should work.

"events.parquet/exportDay=2015090[89],events.parquet/exportDay=2015091[0-4]"