# Drop duplicates in pyspark time series dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

This is a port of [Read range of files in pySpark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37732766/read-range-of-files-in-pyspark) for spark.

I have time series data in a data frame that looks like this:

```
Index Time Value_A Value_B
0     1    A       A
1     2    A       A
2     2    B       A
3     3    A       A
4     5    A       A
```

I want to drop duplicate in the Value_A and Value_B columns such that duplicates are only dropped until a different pattern is encountered. The result for this sample data should be:

```
Index Time Value_A Value_B
0     1    A       A
2     2    B       A
3     3    A       A
```

Comment: You need a window function.

Comment: Could you maybe add a few more examples? E.g. extend your dataframe and desired output to be a bit longer? I think I can see your pattern but not sure. Also, write out the data in a way that is easy to copy paste.