# Read range of parquet files in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, hdfs

I have a ton of daily files stored in an HDFS where the partitions are stored in YYYY-MM-DD format.

For example:

```bash
$ hdfs dfs -ls /my/path/here
<some stuff here> /my/path/here/cutoff_date=2023-10-02
<some stuff here> /my/path/here/cutoff_date=2023-10-03
<some stuff here> /my/path/here/cutoff_date=2023-10-04
<some stuff here> /my/path/here/cutoff_date=2023-10-05
<some stuff here> /my/path/here/cutoff_date=2023-10-06
```

How can I read a range of dates given this structure? In particular, I need to read all the partitions available between `2023-06-07` and `2023-10-06`.

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37732766/read-range-of-files-in-pyspark), I may be able to use `sqlContext` to pass a range using `[]`. Something along the lines of:

```py
sqlContext.read.load('/my/path/here/cutoff_date=[2023-10-02-2023-10-06]')
```

which obviously doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

as `/my/path/here/cutoff_date=[2023-10-02-2023-10-06]` appears to be a linux shell command, perhaps
`/my/path/here/cutoff_date=2023-10-{02..06}`

Comment: I believe this would read the days 2, 3, 4, 5, and 6. Do you know if the same can be done for multiple months (2023-06-01 -> 2023-10-31)?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps reading the partitions needed as below and then union-ing them in order to have one final dataframe will do what you want? change `timedelta` to taste.

EDIT: In case some of the dates data are missing in the range a function called `path_exists` is also created so that you dont have an exception / file not found error in that case

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import subprocess

def path_exists(hdfs_path):
    try:
        subprocess.check_output(['hdfs', 'dfs', '-ls', hdfs_path])
        return True
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        return False

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

start_date = datetime.strptime("2023-06-07", "%Y-%m-%d")
end_date = datetime.strptime("2023-10-06", "%Y-%m-%d")
delta = timedelta(days=1)

date_list = []
while start_date <= end_date:
    date_str = start_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    date_list.append(date_str)
    start_date += delta

df_list = []
for d in date_list:
    hdfs_path = f'/my/path/here/cutoff_date={d}'
    if path_exists(hdfs_path):
        df_list.append(spark.read.load(hdfs_path))

if df_list:
    final_df = df_list[0]
    for df in df_list[1:]:
        final_df = final_df.union(df)
else:
    print("No valid partitions found in the range.")
```

Answer (score 1):

`[]` is a string range like you see in regex.

So for 10/2 to 10/6, `cutoff_date=2023-10-0[2-6]`.

For 6/7 to 10/06, is a little tricky. You can try `cutoff_date=2023-[0-1][0-6]-[0-3][0-9]` but this will include dates like 2023-10-07, 2023-10-20, etc.
So, you'll need additional filter after reading.

However, to be honest, if you are reading somewhat large data, because of `PartitionFilters`, I think reading the whole folder and do the filter vs reading the subset would have only a marginal difference.

ref: https://mungingdata.com/apache-spark/partition-filters-pushed-filters/